# gSOAP WSSE Header missing xmlns namespace declarations

Tags: c++, web-services, wsdl, gsoap, wsse

I have a problem generating a gSOAP security header (WSSE). I have compiled all the necessary file and used the following calls to add the WSSE security header to the request:

```
soap_wsse_add_Security(proxy.soap);
soap_wsse_add_UsernameTokenText(proxy.soap, "UsernameToken-1", "user","passwd");
```

My security header comes out looking like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
      <wsse:Username>testuser</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
    testPassword</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

Compared to the server specification I was provided, the line

```
<wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">
```

is missing the **xmlns:wsse="http...."** 
and the line

```
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
```

is missing the **xmlns:wsu="http...."** parts.
So I want the to look like this:

```
 <wsse:Security  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"  SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">
  <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"  wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
```

How do I add the xmlns:wsse and xmlns:wsu parts to the specific lines to be inline with the spec? The error I get from the service is:

```
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace
    prefix "wsse"
```

I have looked at the gSOAP documentation but all I could find was how to add a header, nothing on how to add namespace definitions to the items in the header.

Assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell me how you add security header to a proxy object? I assume your above proxy variable is DeviceBindingProxy type, but I cannot see any such field in DeviceBindingProxy class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answering the question to close it.

What you need to do is to edit the *.nsmap file. There you can add your namespace definitions in the struct for example:

```
SOAP_NMAC struct Namespace ZamtelWSZambia_namespaces[] =
{
    {"wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-ecext-1.0.xsd", NULL, NULL},
    {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}
};
```

Then in the client simply include the NSMAP like this:

```
#include "soapstubs/XXXX.nsmap"
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you should not edit the .nsmap file, but rather the typemap.dat, which affects the automatic generation of .nsmap.

Use WS\WS-typemap.dat as a base (it already defines WS-SE namespaces) and provide it as an argument to wsdl2h command:

```
wsdl2h -t WS-typemap.dat ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! Been a while since I've had to use gSoap, but you are 100% correct!